# Why does pattern matching records in Erlang throw error

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching, record

Hello i am trying to use record syntax in Erlang  to both bind a variable to the enclosing record and to one of its fields and i keep getting this error:

> d:/Erlang/AeRlang/rec.erl:19: syntax error before: child
>
> d:/Erlang/AeRlang/rec.erl:17: function isMale/1 undefined
>
> d:/Erlang/AeRlang/rec.erl:17: Warning: function maleChildren/1 is
> unused

```
-module(rec).
-export([makeFam/0]).

-record(man,{name,
             age,
             children=[]}).
-record(child,{
    name,
    age,
    sex
}).

makeFam()->
    #man{name="Adrian",
         age=33,
         children=[#child{name="Daniel",age=33,sex="Male"},
                   #child{name="Chris" ,sex="Male"},
                   #child{name="Anne",age=33,sex="Female"}]
        }.


fatherAndSons(Man#man{children=Ch})->{Man,[Elem|| Elem<-Ch,isMale(Elem)]}.
    
isMale(C#child{_,_,Y})->
    case Y of 
        "Male"->true;
         _ ->false
    end.
```

What is wrong in my `isMale` method.I am binding the enclosing structure `#child` to the variable `C` and i am also pattern matching on of its fields.What is the problem ?

**P.S**: Does it have to do with the fact that in `isMale` method i did not specify the name of the field of which i binded the variable `Y`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For both the `fatherAndSons/1` and `isMale/1` functions, you're using the wrong syntax for matching a record as a function argument. Here are some corrected versions:

```
fatherAndSons(Man=#man{children=Ch}) -> {Man, [Elem || Elem <- Ch, isMale(Elem)]}.

isMale(#child{sex="Male"})-> true;
isMale(_) -> false.
```

In the function head for `fatherAndSons/1` we're essentially saying "`Man` is expected to be a `#man` record whose `children` field we'll bind to `Ch`". The `=` operator is what does the matching, but you were missing that for the `Man` binding.

For `isMale/1` I'm using two clauses, where the first clause matches all `#child` records whose `sex` field matches the string `"Male"`and the second clause matches anything else. If you want to keep the second clause restricted to matching only `#child` records, you could instead use:

```
isMale(#child{sex="Male"})-> true;
isMale(#child{}) -> false.
```

Either way, note that there's no need to bind the record to a variable in the function head for `isMale/1` since you don't need the binding in the function body.

Comment: But i am using without `=` because this is how it appears in [Learn you a Erlang for great good](https://learnyousomeerlang.com/a-short-visit-to-common-data-structures#records) when pattern matching the entire structure , although not as a function argument but inside the method. (Check the method `repairman`)

Comment: In the `repairman` function to which you refer, the line `Details = Rob#robot.details` means "Bind `Details` to the value of the `details` field of `Rob`, which is an instance of a `#robot` record." In other words, in that context `Rob` is already bound to a `#robot` record, unlike in your case where you're trying to bind `Man` to a `#man` record in the function head.

Comment: Thank you for your thoroughly explanation !

Answer (score 1):

There are some wrongs in the way get `sex` in your `child record`. You can change your functions `fatherAndSons/1` and `isMale/1` like below:

```
fatherAndSons(Man#man{children=Ch})->{Man,[Elem|| Elem<-Ch,isMale(Elem) == true]}.

isMale(C)->
    case C#child.sex of 
        "Male"->true;
         _ ->false
    end.
```

Or just remove your `isMale/1` and pattern matching in list comprehension:

```
fatherAndSons(Man#man{children=Ch})->
    {Man, [Elem || Elem <-Ch, Elem#child.sex == "Male"]}.
```

Comment: But why is there a problem since i bind the variable directly on the `isMale` argument and then pattern match on it while you bind in the `case` clause.What is wrong ?

Comment: You're not wrong in pattern match in `case` clause. You're wrong in the way get variable `Y` in record `child`.  You can only change the line `isMale(C#child{_,_,Y})->` into `isMale(#child{sex = Y})->`